# Finite Dimensional $ \frac{V}{U} $ imply that $ V $ is finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

as the title suggests, it is true that given a vector space $V$ and a subspace $U$ and that $ {V} \backslash {U} $ is finite dimensional, does that implies that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried considering some example, maybe with U equal to V?

Answer (score 3):

No. For example $V/V\cong\{0\}$ is finite dimensional.

For a less trivial example, take $V=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots):a_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and
$$T:V\to V,\quad T(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=(a_1,0,0,\ldots).$$
Then, $V/\ker(T)\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks got it.